# NullPointerException in onCreate() when using findViewById - setContentView is used before?

Tags: android

Hello I'm writing a little Android app (Version 2.3.3). Now i get this strange NullPointer Exception in this very basic code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

newDeck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newDeckB);
loadDeck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadDeckB);
viewEdition = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewEditionB);

newDeck.setOnClickListener(this);
loadDeck.setOnClickListener(this);
viewEdition.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Im using this simple layout at the moment in main menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button android:id="@+id/newDeckB"
        android:text="New Deck"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/loadDeckB"
        android:text="Load Deck"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/viewEditionB"
        android:text="View Edition"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/currentDeckTextView"
        android:text="Default Deck"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now my problem is a nullpointexception in line 25, which is the line where i set the first clickListener

```
newDeck.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Using the debugger i figured out that the button newDeck is null. I searched a lot in the web but the only answer to such kind of problem was to check that the setContentView is set before the findViewById. This is obviously the case here.

I would be very glad for any kind of advice.

Thx in Before!

Comment: Does `R.id.newDeckB` actually exist in `R.layout.mainmenu`?

Comment: I was having the exact same problem (frustrating!), and it was the comment below (@manelizzard) that solved it for me: 'Sometimes you need to "clean" and rebuild the project to get the correct resurces compiled, it's something from Eclipse'. (i.e. you don't need to use `onPostCreate()` !)

Comment: Clean & rebuild works... how strange.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get your views and set the listeners in onPostCreate() method.

Comment: Thx a lot for your posts.

I don't really understand why but now it works. 

I just changed the id-Names in both the java code and the xml (from newDeckB to newDeckButton) and now it works. I really don't get it because i tried that already yesterday and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Sometimes you need to "clean" and rebuild the project to get the correct resurces compiled, it's something from Eclipse. The onPostCreate() method is executed when the content is fully loaded. Accept the answer, plz =)

Comment: Soory i searched the faq but still don't see a button to accept an answer. Or to set this topic to solved... Sorry i am zoo nooby.

Comment: Click on the Check icon on the left of the answer: http://cdn.sstatic.net/img/faq/faq-accept-answer.png

Comment: Thx again. Sometimes its so simple.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, `onPostCreate` is really meant for framework use, and typically is not expected to be used in applications. Any logic should be contained at the end of `onCreate` instead.

Comment: @manelizzard but im changing the content view after `onCreate()`!. Getting null with `findViewById()`.

Answer (score -2):

There are two events that the App expects, onCreate(), and onStart()

Which one you put this function in, matters.

I had to move "findViewByID" from onCreate() to onStart()

```
    @Override
protected void onStart() {
         // use findViewById() here instead of in onCreate()
    }
```

Comment: Include more info please.

Comment: There are two events that the App expects, onCreate(), and onStart()

Which one you put this function in, matters.